# Writing Active record to search based on all values in a table field

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, rails-activerecord

I want to search based on all locations , i am storing locations as a cookie.
I want to search and get result like this, list properties in locations `Delhi NCR or Mumbai or Pune or Hyderabad or Bangalore or Chennai or Coimbatore or Cochin`

I've written an active record like this:

```
@location = cookies[:location_id] (here iam getting all locations)
@properties=Property.where("location LIKE ?", "%#{@location}%")
```

So, I got sql query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE (location LIKE '%Delhi NCR,Mumbai,Pune,Hyderabad,Bangalore,Chennai,Coimbatore,Cochin%')`
```

seperated by comma, and also not getting search result if any location name is present in table. 
how to search according to all locations and list if any present?

Please help.
Any help is appreciatable

Comment: paste how exactly you are getting locations

Comment: getting like this `"Delhi NCR,Mumbai,Pune,Hyderabad,Bangalore,Chennai,Coimbatore,Cochin"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@location = cookies[:location_id]
@properties=Property.where("location IN (?)", @location.split(","))
```

Try this